# Connecting to Local SQL Server 2008 from my Application

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, database-connection

I am working on an Android App for my friend database class and I am a bit in a bind. I am having troubles establishing my connection. Can someone assist me with this? I have a local database, I don't know much about MS SQL server. Here is the information:

```
ip = "Ip address"; // i am inserting IPV4 IP of computer in this
        db = "testing";
        un = "xee";
        pass = "1995";
        port = "1433";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip +":"+port+";"+ "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="+ password + ";";
        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error when trying to connect

```
E/error here 1 :: Network error IOException: failed to connect to /***.***.*.*** (port 1433) from /:: (port 35033): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Comment: It is fairly bad practice to allow your Android app to connect directly to a SQL Server instance (although what you are trying should be possible).  Is there any reason why you are allowing this direct connection?

Comment: i don't know much about SQL it is a new task for me as I said, a Few days ago I connect MySQL with my app directly, Is there any possibility to connect directly or any other method ?

Comment: The standard pattern is to connect your app to a web service, maybe running in the cloud, and that service is what would actually hit your database.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user name / password definitely correct? 
Is your SQL Server configured to 'mixed' authentication mode? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017
Does the user account have sufficient permissions to access the database? Try setting the login account to be 'sysadmin', which will give it maximum privileges.

Check the Firewall (not if it's a local DB)

Comment: yes username/ password is correct but i never check Firewall , should i off ?

Comment: If the DB is local then the firewall won't matter. If the database is on a remote computer then make sure the SQL Server port is open (1433 by default).